# reading an array from right to left

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, reverse, selection-sort

ok, so I am suppose to get the algorithm of the selection sort, but modify it were it read from right to left and places the largest number at the end of the array. For example the array  {3, 5, 2, 1, 4} will be { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}. You may say just use the regular sort and then reverse the result, but that is not the way I am looking for. So I attempted this and came up with this result.

```
reverseSelectionSort( A[0...n-1])
{
    for(int i=n-1; i=>1; i--)
    {
        int min = i;
        for(int j=i-1; j=>0; j--)
        {
            if(A[j] < A[min])
            {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        swap(A[i], A[min])
    }
}
```

Ok, that is what I came up with. Did I do the algorithm correctly?

Comment: Do you have a reason to suspect you didn't implement it correctly? If so, why?

Comment: You should add a tag that indicates what programming language you're using.

Comment: I use java, but this is more of a pseudo- codish, I just want to be sure that i did it right

Comment: Do you mean >= instead of =>?

Comment: Hey, at least I did an attempt at it instead of asking someone to do it.

Comment: oh, yea, I meant to do >=